# Laravel, Javascript file is not found

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

```
@extends('template')
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.js"></script>
@section('title')
{{ $student->name }} - Student Detail
@endsection
@section('main')
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12" >
      <header>
        <h3><strong>{{ $student->name }}</strong> <a href="#"><img src="../img/kattis.png" alt="Kattis" width="20" height="15"></a> in CS3233 S1 AY 2020/21</h3>
        <p><strong>SPE</strong>(ed) component: <strong>{{ $student->mc }} + {{ $student->tc }} = {{ $student->mc+$student->tc }}</strong><br>
          <strong>DIL</strong>(igence) component: <strong>{{ $student->hw }} + {{ $student->bs }} + {{ $student->ks }} + {{ $student->ac }} = {{ $student->hw+$student->bs+$student->ks+$student->ac }}</strong><br>
          <strong>Sum = SPE + DIL = {{ $student->mc+$student->tc }} + {{ $student->hw+$student->bs+$student->ks+$student->ac }} = {{ $student->mc+$student->tc+$student->hw+$student->bs+$student->ks+$student->ac }}</strong></p>
        </header>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <img class="pull-right" id="photo" src="@if($student->avatar) {{Storage::url($student->avatar)}} @else ../img/locked.png @endif" alt="Photo of {{ $student->name }}" width="100" height="100">
        <img class="pull-right" id="flag" src="../flags/4x3/{{strtolower($student->country)}}.svg" alt="{{$student->country}} Flag" width="100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas></div>
  @endsection
@section('footer')
  <script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'radar',
      labels: ["MC", "TC", "HW", "Bs", "KS", "Ac"],
      data: [$student->mc,$student->tc,$student->hw,$student->bs,$student->ks,$student->ac]

  });
  </script>
@endsection
```

In this file, called `detail.blade.php`, I include `Chart.js`. This file is located in `public/js`. `detail.blade.php` is in the directory with all the other views. In `index.blade.php`, I successfully referenced javascript files in the exact same way, for example

```
@section('footer')
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highlight.js"></script>
@endsection
```

. But in detail.blade.php, it doesn't work. I get the error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` regarding `Chart.js`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Chart.js"></script>
```

This line does not form part of any section so it's not included. You need to include it in some section (e.g. main or footer)

Comment: I put it in main. Now this error is generated: GET https://app.lzr.im/student/js/Chart.js

Comment: change src to `/js/Chart.js`. I've updated my answer. If it solves your issue, do accept my answer. If not, please post the error

Answer (score 0):

Try
      `<script src="{{ URL::asset('/js/Chart.js') }}"></script>`

I think your js folder is in public if it's taht you gonna have acess to your script with this link.